# Not able to get correct records in query - php mysql

Tags: mysql, join

I am running the following query.

```
SELECT * 
  FROM exam, result 
 WHERE exam.home = result.external_id 
   AND exam.away != result.external_id;
```

Records in the *exam* table:

```
home   away
51156   8
51158   7
51158  51182
```

Records in *result* table:

```
external_id
51156
51158
51182
```

In normal scenario, the first two records should be fetched. Now when I use the '!=' independently, it executes without an issue. Means, when I execute

```
SELECT * FROM exam, result WHERE exam.away != result.external_id
```

it is executed correctly. This is the result.

```
home   away
51156   8
51158   7
```

However, in my above mentioned erroneous query, the output is as follows:

```
id  home   away
111 51156   8
100 51158   7
123 51158  51182
```

The last row it is considered though it should not be counted. Can anyone tell me why? Or any alternative for the query?

Comment: I don't quite understand exactly what data you are trying to get - what are you trying to describe?

Comment: @BasicGem Do you want only the records that do _not_ have an id on the column `away` which is in the table `result`?

Comment: I want records for which column home is present in result and away is not present in result. I want to combine both of them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To my understanding you are looking for records which do not have an id on the column `away` that is present in the table `result`.

If that is the case, then this query will produce the result you want:

```
SELECT *
  FROM exam
 WHERE home IN (SELECT external_id FROM result)
   AND away NOT IN (SELECT external_id FROM result)
```

Comment: Shef, Thanks for your answer. But I also need to put one more condition that exam.home = result.external_id along with the condition of away != external_id. How can i do that? I tried combining by using your query, but mysql throws error.

Comment: @BasicGem So you want those records from `exam` which have the same id in the column `home` with any record in `result`, but do not have the same id in the column `away` with any record in `result`? I updated my answer, hope that will solve it.

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
SELECT e.home,e.away,r.external_id
FROM exam e join result r on r.external_id = e.home and e.away != r.external_id 
where e.away not in (select r.external_id from result r)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT *  
  FROM exam  
 WHERE home IN (SELECT external_id FROM result WHERE exam.home = result.external_id)  
   AND away IN (SELECT external_id FROM result WHERE exam.away!= result.external_id )
```